# Command-F (search) in Finder

Tags: finder

As shown in the screenshot when I do a command-F (Find files ?) all of the files in the directory just do not show anymore (there are hundreds of files in the /shared directory)

**Update** ***Of course / naturally*** I typed in values to the search field. E.g pdf  I also used the dropdowns (type PDF). No change - i.e. nothing shows up.

So what is going on with the command-F.

BEFORE command-F

[image]

AFTER command-F  (nothing??)

[image]

Comment: why are you missing the search filed entry in your cmd+f? or is it just not showing in your screen shot!

Comment: as soon you type anything in the search field they will show....

Comment: did you end up installing xtrafinder? that program re-maps many of Finder’s key combinations...

Comment: @njboot  I just installed it .. *after* the above issues surfaced.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to specify what you want to search. As soon as you begin typing your query the results will appear.

From [OS X: Keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

> Command-F Find any matching Spotlight attribute

As long as nothing is entered there is no match.

If you just want to move the input focus to the search field without starting a search use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: of course i tried that.